# Nexmo sms API on PHP return false but not on browser

Tags: php, curl, vonage

```
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=xxx&api_secret=xxx&from=NEXMO&to=xxxxx&text=Welcome+to+Nexmo';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

When I executed it, the response was null.

but when I access the url on browser, It gives api.txt files which has the response and I get the sms which I just send using that url.

Comment: if the response was null, please check for curlerror, try catch it, and you will know what caused the null :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried the same code:

```
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=KEY&api_secret=SECRET&from=NEXMO&to=TO_NUMBER&text=Welcome+to+Nexmo';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo($response);
```

And I get the response:

```
{
    "message-count": "1",
    "messages": [{
        "to": "TO_NUMBER",
        "message-id": "MESSAGE_ID",
        "status": "0",
        "remaining-balance": "7.25697349",
        "message-price": "0.03330000",
        "network": "23415"
    }]
}%
```

As you can see, the response seems to be populated. So, it seems to work.

I'd personally recommend using the [nexmo-php](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-php) library since it's officially supported by Nexmo (who I work for).

```
$client = new Nexmo\Client(new Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic(API_KEY, API_SECRET));

$message = $client->message()->send([
    'to' => NEXMO_TO,
    'from' => NEXMO_FROM,
    'text' => 'Test message from the Nexmo PHP Client'
]);
```